# Brute force integer factorization - back of the envelope calculation

Tags: rsa, factoring

RSA-240, an integer with 240 decimal digits from the original [RSA Factoring Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge), has [recently been factorized](https://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=NMBRTHRY;fd743373.1912&FT=M&P=T&H=&S=).

According to the researchers, the factorization took a total of 900 core-years on a 2.1 GHz Intel Xeon Gold 6130 CPU:

> RSA-240 sieving:  800 physical core-years
>
> RSA-240 matrix:   100 physical core-years

Just as a theoretical exercise, I'd like to understand how this computing cost ranks against the (purely theoretical) cost of brute-forcing the factorization.

By brute-forcing, I mean basically trying out every single integer `n`, starting with `n=2`, and checking if `RSA-240 % n = 0`, i.e. if RSA-240 can be divided by `n` without a remainder. This is, of course, incredibly inefficient - we know RSA-240 to be the product of two prime numbers, and most integers `n` aren't primes, so there's no point in testing them. I'm kinda looking for a base line here with no optimizations whatsoever.

The factorization of RSA-240 revealed

```
244624208838318150567813139024002896653802092578931401452041221336558477095178155258218897735030590669041302045908071447
```

as the lower of the two prime factors, which a decimal with 120 digits, therefore a number between $10^{119}$ and $10^{120}$. Let's call that number `p` and the other factor `q`.

So the brute force approach would have had to try that many numbers `n` until it would arrived at `p` and realized that `RSA-240 % p = 0`. Computing `q = RSA-240 / p` is then, of course, trivial.

So let's say the cost of computing `RSA-240 % n` is `c` CPU cycles.

Even if `c=1` (on some specialized hardware with very wide registers), on a ~2 GHz CPU, we could check 2B = 2  x  $10^9$ numbers per second. So, checking all the numbers up to `p` would take approximately $10^{120} / (10^9) = 10^{110}\text{ seconds} = 10^{103} \text{ years}$ (there are 31,536,000 seconds in a year, that's about $10^{7}$) - an incredibly long amount of time, and about $10^{100}$ times as long as the 900 core-years the researchers managed to achieve.

Is my math about right, or am I missing something?

Comment: Your math is right. Brute force is completely impossible. Algorithms for factorisation are sub-exponential, and much much faster than a naive exponential brute force search.

Comment: That so-called trial division is hopeless for large numbers, even if we apply the common optimizations. Usually trial division is carried only with a reduced selection of $n$: after testing $n=2$ and $n=3$, we do not need to test $n$ multiple of $2$ or $3$, that is we need only to test $n$ of the form $6k\pm1$, saving a factor of $3$. But if we extend this saving strategy to the first million primes, we save only a factor $\lesssim29.5$.